# Are there any good alternatives to WebSVN?

Tags: svn, websvn

We've been using it for the past few years and not the most happy with it at the moment.  Is there any good alternatives out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) provides a very nice interface to Subversion - I prefer it to the WebSVN views.

In addition, it adds many other features, as well.

Comment: same here but it won't do multiple repositories!

Comment: I will with multiple Trac setups... but a single trac setup will only do a single repository.

Comment: admittedly we wound up going with Trac. (as it was already installed) We were close on FishEye as we liked the statistics but it wound up giving us some slowness problems.  Warehouse & InDefero didn't have a windows install, and I couldn't figure out how to do comparisons between revisions in ViewVC.

Answer (score 5):

[ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) is another popular one.  If you install the CollabNet Subversion Server, ViewVC can be installed as an optional component.

[ViewVC In Action On A Live Repo](http://svn.collab.net/viewvc/svn/)

The Subversion Project Web Site also has [a list of repo browsing tools](http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#browsers)

Comment: Thanks for that link! Just what I needed - Finally! a browser that doesn't need ruby / java / php etc ..... just bog standard python/cgi as installed on 99.999999 nix distros and it works great!

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend Atlassian's [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/).

It's a fantastic product.

The only downside (if you can call it that) is that it is a commercial (not free) product, but if you happen to be working on an open source project, it is free.

You can see it in action if you check out the [Spring Framework](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-framework) open source project.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net), this is a clone of GoogleCode available for free.

Comment: just to be aware, its not just another svn hosting site, they also provide the source for the webapp under the GPL. http://www.indefero.net/open-source/

Answer (score 1):

I'd give [Warehouse](https://github.com/entp/warehouse) a try. It looks very nice and should come with the same feature set as WebSVN.

Comment: It seems to be down now.

Comment: @tricasse fixed the broken link

Comment: Thanks. The project seems abandoned for now (5 years without any changes).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it has the features you're looking for or not, I don't have experience with WebSVN, but we have been using [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com) for over a year and have been pretty happy.

Comment: FYI: This appears to be a hosted option only (I didn't down vote you).